# Switch statement by id in jQuery ui to show different menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, jquery-ui

I am trying to develop a slide effect to show the main manu of my wordpress webpage. Depending of the id of the div clicked I need select the submenu to show. This is the code that I have but I don´t know why it doesnt work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#header-menu > li > a').click(function(){

        var id=jQuery(this).attr('id');

        switch (id) {

        case 'menu-item-group':
            jQuery('#secondary-menu_group > li').css('display','block');
            break;
        default:
            jQuery('.secondary-menu > li').css('display','block');
        } 
        jQuery('#secondary-menu-wrap').effect('slide',{direction: 'up'}, 500);
    });
});
```

It always enter in the "default" statement.
I tried too with " case '#menu-item-group':" but it doesnt work too.

Comment: Can we see the HTML? Is the id attribute on the `a` tag?

Comment: Can you show us an example in jsfiddle ?

Comment: @JacobMattison Sorry I am doing a big mistake. I am listening the click event of 'a' and trying to find coincidences with the id of th 'li'. When you mentioned the 'a' tag I know that...

Comment: Yep, that was my suspicion.  You're not the first.  Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was searching coincidences with the incorrect id. 
Thanks